# How to make a simple and quick citation

Tags: bibliographies

I have been following this simple and clean commands to create a quick reference.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
  .....
\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\bibitem{lamport94}
  Leslie Lamport,
  \emph{\LaTeX: A Document Preparation System}.
  Addison Wesley, Massachusetts,
  2nd Edition,
  1994.


\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

### but it says undefined control sequence as following

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \@listctr 

l.949 \bibitem{lamport94}
```

--------------------------------------------------------UPDATE

I am not sure if this counts as successful compilation, but after clicking enter serveral times in TextWork, It finally brought me to something like this
[image]

If you could zoom in the map, you will find the reference doesn't behave as expected. 'thebibliography' somehow slipped into the text

Comment: I'm afraid I get no error messages when I run your code. What happens if you remove the .aux file and recompile?

Comment: I am afraid it's always as this even though after removal .aux file

Comment: I augmented your code fragment into an MWE (minimum working example) by adding the instruction `\documentclass{article}` (and by fixing a typo). As it now stands, the MWE compiles fine on my system; does it compile correctly on yours too? Does your document have additional aspects not mentioned in the MWE that might be causing the error message?

Comment: Your image doesn't show the result of the MWE! Please fix this.

Comment: Please refer to my update. I can get around the undefined control by clicking <enter>, and it finally brought me to somewhere as displayed in the picture

Comment: I have "\documentclass[pdftex,12pt,a4paper]{report}" at very beginning. It's a long report

Comment: @Daniel Please work on your example: the `report` class defines standard list structures, so it is not a 'normal' issue. You will need to make a copy of your report and cut it down until you find the minimum needed to reproduce the problem. Without a MWE we won't be able to help, I'm afraid.

Comment: If I've deciphered your screenshot correctly, you have a line saying `begin{thebibliography}{9}` (note: no backslash character) between `\begin{thebibliography}{9}` and the first `\bibitem` statement. The material `begin{thebibliography}{9}` will be treated as ordinary text, i.e., it will be rendered as `beginthebibliography9`. You need to delete that line.

Comment: oh  yeah. what a careless mistake. Bright eyes. thanks Mico!!!

Comment: OK, I'll post this comment as an answer, so that your posting can be considered to have been "answered".

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not helpful for other users.

Comment: wait ... one more thing

Comment: It seems to be caused by "\usepackage{apacite}" this package. the duplication is not the real case, I still got the same error after removing it

Comment: @Daniel - Please see my reply to the comment you posted on my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that the first line in the bibliography (the Lamport reference) currently starts with `beginthebibliography9` is due to the following code:

```
\begin{thebibliography}{9}
begin{thebibliography}{9}
\bibitem{lamport94}
...
```

You need to delete the middle line, i.e., the one that says

```
begin{thebibliography}{9}
```

Comment: Sorry in some not shown part of the tex file(It's really a big file). I have included "\usepackage{apacite}" in the preamble. This seemed to be causing the error when I tried your suggestion to find a MWE. Removing it solve everything. Do you know why it could cause a problem?

Comment: @Daniel - Loading the `apacite` package would make sense if you used BibTeX and the `apacite` bibliography style. The `apacite` package is quite large and sophisticated, and I wouldn't be surprised if it modified the syntax of the `\bibitem` macro. Since it looks like you're building the bibliography "by hand", I'd say there's no need to load the `apacite` package.

Comment: suuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuure:)